# Proving a series goes to infinity

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Demonstrate the Taylor series $\sum\limits_{n\geq 1}^{\infty}z^{n!}$ has radius of convergece $R =1$, and the analystic function $g(z)=\sum\limits_{n\geq 1}^{\infty}z^{n!}$ has the following property:$$
> \lim_{r \to 1^-} |g(re^{2x\pi i})| = \infty. \quad \forall x\in \mathbb{Q}
> $$

$\mathbf{\underline{Solution}}:$

Obviously, we see that $$ 
   a_n = \begin{cases}
        1;& n = m! \\ 0;& \text{otherwise}
                \end{cases}$$
So, $$\varlimsup_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_n=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sup_{k \geq n} a_k=1\\\Rightarrow R=\frac{1}{\varlimsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_n}=1,$$ as required.

For the second part that I am struggling with. This is my attempt.

$$\begin{align*}g(re^{2\pi ix})&=\sum_{n=1}^b\left(re^{2\pi ix}\right)^{n!}+\sum_{n=b+1}^{\infty}\left(re^{2\pi ix}\right)^{n!}\\ &=\sum_{n=1}^b\left(re^{2\pi ix}\right)^{n!}+\sum_{n=b+1}^{\infty}r^{n!}\left(e^{2\pi ia}\right)^{n!/b}\\ &=\sum_{n=1}^b\left(re^{2\pi ix}\right)^{n!}+\sum_{n=b+1}^{\infty}r^{n!}.\end{align*}$$ This shows that $$|g(re^{2\pi ix})|=|\sum_{n=b+1}^{b+q}r^{n!}+\sum_{n=b+q+1}^{\infty}r^{n!}+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(re^{2\pi i x})^{n!}|, q \geq 1.$$ So, I want to show that $$\sum_{n=1}^{b+q}r^{n!}\xrightarrow[r\to 1^-]{}\infty.$$
I want to show $\forall M>0 $, $\exists r_0<1$, such that for some $r_0<r<1$
$|\sum_{n=1}^{b+q}r^{n!}| \geq M$.
Let $M>0$
I am getting stuck here with finding such an $r_0$ depending on M.
So I appreciate any help with that. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your sum doesn't diverge until $\infty$. For every $r<1$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, you have $r^{n!} < r < 1$ which mean that your sum is less than $b+q$. You need then to prove that another one of your 3 sums diverge.

Comment: Yeah that is my problem so what should I do with that

Comment: If $x \in \mathbb{N}$ then $g(r e^{2i\pi x}) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}r^{n!}$. So you should probably prove that this sum $\sum_{n=b+q+1}^{\infty}r^{n!}$ diverges (since $\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{Q}$).

Comment: I got one idea. If we take $\frac{1}{kn} \leq r^{n!}$ for k being large enough would that work

Comment: I'm not sure such a $k$ exists. Because $r^{n!}*n < r^{n}*n \to 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making things too complicated. Once you get $g(re^{2 \pi i x}) =\sum_{n=1}^{b} (re^{2 \pi i x})^{n!}+\sum_{n=b+1}^{\infty} r^{n!}$ just let $r \to 1$. The first term has a finite limit whereas $\lim_{r \to 1} \sum_{n=b+1}^{\infty} r^{n!} \geq \lim_{r \to 1} \sum_{n=b+1}^{N} r^{n!}=(N-b)$ for each integer $N>b+1$. Hence $lim_{r \to 1} \sum_{n=b+1}^{\infty} r^{n!}=\infty$.

Comment: OK. I get it thank you